# How do you get the position of a special character in an array on tasker

Tags: regex, special-characters, tasker

I am trying to get the position of a special character in an array using tasker but I have had no luck. I have tried the following %Variable(#?+) but this returns 0. I tried this because if you are trying to get the position of a word in an array you type in %Variable(#?data)however this does not work for special characters.

Comment: Please provide some sample inputs and outputs in your question. What do you mean by special character?

Comment: The input is %Variable(#?+), with the special character as +. The output would be 0 if nothing is found or the number of positon of the character. Don't worry I have found a solution now it should be %Variable(#?~R\+). Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

As per Tasker [Pattern Matching](https://tasker.joaoapps.com/userguide/en/matching.html) documentation, "*Standard Java regular expression matching is applied*" "*wherever a Simple Match is possible, by preceding the regex with **~R** or **!~R***".

Thus you need to escape the `+` and use `~R`:

```
%Variable(#?~R\+)
```